# Meaning of @output and @item on this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

Based on last investigation, I browse for the SQL Function which contain this :

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAliasesByWo]
(
    @item nvarchar(max),
    @length float,
    @catego nvarchar(max),
    @opt nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @output varchar(max)
    select @output = COALESCE(@output + ', ', '') + wo_lot + '=' + convert(nvarchar, wo_qty_ord)
    FROM    wo_mstr_data 
    where wo_part = @item and 
          wo__dec01 = @length and
          wo__chr01 = @catego and 
          RIGHT(wo_rmks,1) = @opt and
          wo_status = 'R' and
          SUBSTRING(wo_routing,1,4) = 'PROF' 

    return @output
END
```

My question is, :

1. Whats the meaning of @output and @items on those queries ? is @output is the result of this function ? other @ seems like fieldnames
2. I didn't get the clue about "declaring the output till selecting the output". whats the purpose of that ? how do coalesce will recognize the @output while its not decided yet.

Comment: `@output` is getting the result of the query. the other `@`s are variables you put into the function. Please read the docs on functions. It is all explained there.

Comment: You set values of parameters, call function with these parameters, that select creates variable of `nvarchar` type and set it as `@output` value, which is returned to you at end of function ... coalesce won't recognize `@output`, value of `@output` will be result of `coalesce`

Comment: Time to look up what a variable is I think?

Comment: @juergend well I already try to understand the docs but seems not directly give me the answer ..... it bring me to another question.... well .. your answer is clear enough to understand ... so thanks a lot bruh

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a scalar function.  What is does is you pass 4 parameters to it, a calculation is performed using a SQL query.  What it's doing is concatenating a string, saving this into the output variable, which is ultimately returned.

Comment: @Veljko89 I see .... in this case, is this function returning coalescence result will b like ((wo_lot=wo_qty_order)1, (wo_lot=wo_qty_order)2,...,...,) with all of those where condition parameters ? sorry if my English bad

Comment: This looks like an overly complicated way to get a comma delimited string. And the convert to nvarchar with no size is not a good habit. The size should always be specified. To be honest I would probably convert this to an inline table valued function if I had it. It would be faster and more flexible.

Comment: @SeanLange well after I read the all the answer before and I understand it.... my thought same with you .... and now I try to replace it.

Comment: It is a function which returns a comma delimited string of values, it seems you should change types of input variables.

Comment: @SeanLange - overly complicated and unreliable. The SQL Server docs have, for a *long time* (i.e. back to at least SQL Server 2000) warned that computing aggregates by repeated assignment to scalar variables in a select clause is unreliable because it may evaluate the same row multiple times (or not evaluate some rows)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I don't remember seeing warnings about missing and/or duplicate rows for the type of variable assignment above. I was trying to find this in the documentation but not having any luck. Have a link by chance, I would like to read about it more.

Comment: @SeanLange - yeah, the problem is that the warning appears in the wrong *piece* of documentation. But given the nature of the warning, it's clear that it's talking about `SELECT` and not `SET` - [`SET @local_variable` Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql#remarks): "Do not use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (...). Unexpected query results may occur. This is because all expressions in the SELECT list (...) are not guaranteed to be executed exactly once for each output row"

Comment: (And clear because you cannot do any kind of aggregation in a `SET` statement)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that is interesting. I notice the kb article that actually has the details is now a 404. I can only imagine trying to keep the documentation but sheesh...the MS documentation has gotten so bad the last few years.

Comment: Hi all ... can this function worked in another way (cause I'm using some BI tools to replace the SQL scripting) I try to use only from 'COALESCE ...' row and it works but only returns the First not-null value (used to be ordinary COALESCE command), how to have the looping result like the function above except using that ?